# Programmatically Changing XP Appearance Settings

Tags: windows, windows-xp, registry, appearance

I am trying to silently apply very specific appearance settings for a single user with poor eyesight on an XP machine.

I can alter the settings by using the appearance tab of the display settings dialog and clicking apply/ok. Doing this works however the user cannot see well enough to change her settings back to how she likes them each time she logs on.

Just changing the registry keys does not make the desired changes until the user logs off and then on again. For reasons that would take too long to explain, I cannot simply get the user to log off and then on again. I need the settings to be applied immediately upon login.

So! I either need to force windows to apply the display settings, a process which seems to be associated with the 'Please Wait' dialog, screenshot included OR I need to programmatically change the appearance settings individually (which includes altering 'Advanced' font-size settings).

Many thanks.

[Please Wait Example http://www.dur.ac.uk/alexander.holmes2/b/pleasewait.jpg](http://www.dur.ac.uk/alexander.holmes2/b/pleasewait.jpg)

Comment: I suspect you could set this via group policy for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Does this user have his/her own windows User? (his/her own account on XP). It should keep settings for you if you have them as a separate user from whoever else likes the larger DPI. Just create a user.

Comment: I have found that is not the case, possibly due to the way that group policies are implemented on our domain. I cannot alter these policies easily without an official request for change, long tedious process etc. Furthermore, I do not need to change the DPI, I need to change the font sizes in the appearance settings along with some of the colours.

Comment: After making those changes, have you tried saving them to a theme? Themes are easier than registry changes, or getting a user to do something they don't want to.

Comment: This might be of use as well.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773190(VS.85).aspx
It shows how to actually create .theme files.